# Save data to database asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to save a single piece of data to a table where my user is logged in also, I have created a table connected to my users table through a foreign key. The idea is to take a multiple choice test and have the score saved to the database under the same id as the logged in users ID and the name of the test. I can't seem to find any good resources or code that I can follow and I'm not sure how I can integrate the `asp.identity` system with uploading to the server/database table.

I am very new to all of this and i'm not really sure how to start.

In the current state I have saved the score as a variable but do not know how to proceed.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please show us the code which you have tried? Please don't expect others to write full code for you. Hire a freelancer for that job. Here users volunteer to help other users when they are stuck on a specific programming related problem.

Comment: @SouravGhosh, Im not expecting that at all, i cant find any pages which relate using the asp.identity stuff with sql queries and i'm stumped. I cant start to create a draft of the code i will use because i'm not sure how it works. I just need some direction or where to start

Comment: Really? You looked at the first google result for 'asp identity'? Which has plenty of resources and examples on this... like the fourth one down which describes exactly what you want to do? https://www.asp.net/identity

Answer (score 0):

You did not add your database field, however what i understand, i am answering based on this.

First of all, change the database table like that:

```
 public class ClassName
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        //other
        //field

        //Foreign key
        public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
    }

Then go to your methods, try this, 

[HttpGet]
 public ActionResult Add()
  {
 return View();
 }

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add(ClassName className){

if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
className.ApplicationUserId=User.Identity.GetUserId();
//rest of field
//

db.dbltable.Add(className);
db.SaveChanges();

}
```